# Standalone usage of "tid" from tidbits

Tags: neologisms

Watching an old episode of Home Improvement recently,

> *Eavesdropping Neighbour:* I was just hearing some **tidbits** of your
>   conversation.
>
> *Tim:* Sounds to me like you heard the whole **tid**.

This sounded as a dialogue writer's invention to me. Is there any known usage of the word "tid" to mean the "whole part of something" or does it have any standalone meaning?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The OED has four entries for *tid*, two as a noun, one as a verb and one as an adjective. None has the meaning ‘whole part of something’. The only use associated with *tid-bit* is obsolete. Even then it seems to be little more than a shortened form, as this definition by Johnson suggests:

> *Tid*, adj. (tydder, Saxon), tender; soft; nice‥*Titbi′t* (properly
>   *tidbit*; *tid*, tender, and *bit*), nice bit; nice food.

So, no, I think the writer was just playing with the word. Not that there’s anything wrong with that.